# Why do I get a superfluous operator string at the top of my output when performing a query that includes an arithmetic operation?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using the `=query()` function to get sublists from a table in my sheet.

Assuming an initial dataset like so...

```
Sheet1
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D
-----+-----+-----+-----
 1st | X   |  10 |  20
 2nd | X   |  20 |  20
 3rd | Y   |  30 |  20
 4th | X   |  40 |  10
```

I can then use a query like this to get a sublist...

```
=query(Sheet1!A:D,"select A,C,D where B='X'")
```

Which gives me...

```
 1st |  10 |  20
 2nd |  20 |  20
 4th |  40 |  10
```

One thing I've been having to work around clumsily is the fact that I'm getting and unexpected extra string in the output when I try to use arithmetic operations within the query, something that should be possible according to [Google's reference page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?csw=1#operators).

Assuming I try these queries, for instance...

```
=query(Sheet1!A:D,"select A,C+D where B='X'")
=query(Sheet1!A:D,"select A,C-D+100 where B='X'")
```

...I expect the following...

```
 1st |  30
 2nd |  40
 4th |  50

 1st |  90
 2nd |  100
 4th |  130
```

...which almost works, except I get a superfluous function string at the top, so the output ends up looking like this...

```
       sum()
 1st |  30
 2nd |  40
 4th |  50

       sum(difference()100())
 1st |  90
 2nd |  100
 4th |  130
```

As you can see, the values are correct, except for those annoying strings at the top. Is this a bug? Is there something basic I'm skipping past or using incorrectly? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed normal. In order to get rid of the labels you can set them to blank, like this:

```
=query(B:E;"select B,D+E where C='X' label (D+E)'' ")
```